# Recommendation on authorization flow

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, oauth, asp.net-identity, access-token

I have a simple web application created using ASP.NET MVC. The web app allows user to register using OpenID and then a corresponding record is saved in the DB representing that user. Now, I am creating a second web app that will expose REST APIs (using Web API) which will be called by the first app. This second app is completely separated from the first one (including the DB; also, different classes); the first one just communicates with this using the REST APIs of the 2nd app.

The 2nd app exposes a Register endpoint but right now, anyone can call that endpoint. What I want to achieve is only users in the first app are able to register on the second app. My question is how do I implement this?

I am using ASP.NET Identity on the 2nd app to manage users, but so far, the tutorials I've read always has the Register functionality of the tutorial to be accessible by anyone. I can't put Authorize attribute on the Register endpoint because then, no one would be able to Register but I want to limit the users that are able to Register to be user of the first web app.

Once the user is registered in the 2nd app, I think it will be easy to check authorization on the other REST API using tokens, I just can't think of how to limit the Register endpoint when user records are does not yet exist in the 2nd app.

Can you provide me with a flow on how this can be done?